# Universal link on iOS app opens app but doesn't call handler

Tags: ios, swift, ios-universal-links

I've got an app with a universal link. When I tap the link in another app, it opens my app (except in Safari, it opens the webpage but displays a little banner at top offering to open in the app, tapping "Open" opens my app).

My issue is no code gets executed in my app.

I've put the sample code from [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/supporting-universal-links-in-your-app):

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                 continue userActivity: NSUserActivity,
                 restorationHandler: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void) -> Bool
{
    // Get URL components from the incoming user activity.
    guard userActivity.activityType == NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb,
        let incomingURL = userActivity.webpageURL,
        let components = NSURLComponents(url: incomingURL, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: true) else {
        return false
    }


    // Check for specific URL components that you need.
    guard let path = components.path,
    let params = components.queryItems else {
        return false
    }
    print("path = \(path)")


    if let albumName = params.first(where: { $0.name == "albumname" } )?.value,
        let photoIndex = params.first(where: { $0.name == "index" })?.value {


        print("album = \(albumName)")
        print("photoIndex = \(photoIndex)")
        return true


    } else {
        print("Either album name or photo index missing")
        return false
    }
}
```

I do not have scenes support (so just AppDelegate).

Now I have prints and breakpoints set everywhere in AppDelegate (notably in the function of which the code is above, and in the "application handleOpen url".
When I tap a URL in another app, it brings to my app, but the only method executed is applicationDidBecomeActive.

In other words, I'm unable to get any information from the URL that lead the user to my app... Any idea why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That seems to be an apple bug.

The solution to get the method called is to add this before it:

```
@objc(application:continueUserActivity:restorationHandler:)
```